# What's the point of deactivating Num Lock on login screens?

Tags: usability, login, password, keyboard

Many login screens automatically deactivate the Num Lock key on the keyboard before the user can enter their password. This is extremely frustrating for the user as they involuntarily type their password wrong multiple times before realising the Num Lock key is off.

Several undesirable side effects include:

- Missing the password involuntarily 3 times, thereby locking the system,
- Having a timeout after each missed password attempt, sometimes up to several minutes,
- Frustration when one repeatedly forgets to activate the Num Lock key.

Moreover, I don't see what the reason for this would be from a security viewpoint. It does not enhance the quality of the password nor does it ward off any potential attacker.

So why are very widespread systems still using this extremely frustrating methodology?

Comment: Can you provide an example per your "many" claim? The most prevalent operating system's (Windows') login screen does not exhibit this failure, ahem "feature".

Comment: I never encountered a login screen that deactivates numlock. Are you perhaps mistaking the bios option to turn numlock on or off on boot as a "login screen feature"?

Comment: Not likely to be the answer to the actual question, but: I'd argue that a password you type on the num block is probably not a very good password (either unsafe or so long that it's unnecessarily hard to remember and type). So yeah, turning off the num block _might_ actually enhance password quality, by convincing the user to switch to a password that's more based on letters than numbers.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you seem to assume a password typed exclusively on the number pad, rather than just a few characters; you also seem to assume that a user only uses one type of keyboard to log in to a system. (I have, once, used a system with an ultracompact builtin keyboard with no number row and a USB number pad, as an example of an edge case where this would be particularly irritating)

Comment: @ChrisH if it's just a few numbers in the password then it doesn't make sense to use the num block, the number row is closer. And if you have an ultracompact keyboard with no number row then it certainly seems silly to put any numbers at all in the passwords that you need to type – what if you don't have that USB block with you?

Comment: @leftroundabout once again you're assuming that users only log on to one device per password (that tiny keyboard was on an embedded system on a network that required numbers in the password). On a normal system I personally (and by the sounds of it you as well) would use the number row. Not every user would so it's a silly restriction to impose by assumption.

Comment: At this point I'd be happy with ONE example of a login screen that does this.  I've never seen it.

Comment: @JPhi1618 my Windows 10 Laptop does this.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I only encountered in on Windows. It's usually on laptops. Sometimes it's BIOS, sometimes it's other settings, but one common tip for fixing is to turn on Numlock on the login screen and reboot without loging - that would point to the login screen fault. Also if you google this problem, you'll find many posts with solutions, hinting it's really common. https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+login+screen+numlock+off

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 is it turning off at the login screen or when you reboot? If you log in, turn on num lock, then log out, does it turn back off? My Windows 10 laptop only does it after rebooting, not every time I go to the login screen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the claim is unsubstantiated.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus There will always be people like you who ruin the SE experience for other people. My question is valid, on subject and well-received. Yet here you are, attempting to close the question.

Comment: @Kat I don't even have to log out, if I try to switch account it turns it off. It's a company machine so maybe it's a group policy or something?

Comment: @Klangen there are more up votes on the multiple comments asking you to substantiate this actually happens than there are on your question, so I'm not sure "well-received" is exactly accurate. We do have one example in the comments from Tom where it's definitely tied to the login screen rather than rebooting, but IMO your question would be improved if you edited in where you've seen this in more detail. It's definitely not standard functionality on Windows, so knowing more could help us answer what the purpose is.

Comment: @JPhi1618 All OpenSuSE login screens after 12.3

Comment: @leftaroundabout I regularly have to log in to a system that requires me to type a numerical password immediately followed by a six-digit one-time authorization code.  Doing so without the num block would be annoying, even if they'd allow the initial part of the password to be non-numerical. I assume the OTAC makes it fairly safe though.

Comment: @JPhi1618 For what it's worth, my Windows 10 definitely turns off NumLock right before the login screen. Numlock is On in the BIOS settings, the NumLock green light is on during the boot process and is turned off when the login screen appears.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Here you go : https://download.ericduminil.com/login_numlock_off.mp4

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Some compact keyboard layouts don't have a numpad, so those keys are mapped to the right-hand side of the letter section:
[image]

If NumLock is on, then a user typing the password `kill`, will actually type `2533`. Turning NumLock off will prevent this problem, but of course - it will cause another one for those who *do* rely on the numpad. Keeping it on or off by default will lead to [*mode errors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(user_interface)#Mode_errors) - regardless of what initial state is chosen, someone will be surprised by it.

A better solution would be to *reflect the state* of the NumLock key on the screen, akin to the CapsLock key. This way there are no surprises, as this state indicator is in the users' *locus of attention*.

An example are `Acer Revo` computers, distributed with compact wireless keyboards. I installed a fresh OS and set up a password, then successfully "confirmed" it. However, what I thought I was doing was different from what the computer saw me do. This problem only became evident when I attempted to connect to the machine remotely, from a place with a proper keyboard.

Many hours and "this cannot be" statements later, I undersood that NumLock was the culprit.

Comment: How come the cause of mode errors is keeping NumLock on or off by default, rather than changing NumLock's state without the user's knowledge or will? I'd have thought that *keeping* it on or off by default will lead to the keyboard behaving as the user expects.

Comment: I've got one of those keyboards for when I need to log in locally to a normally-headless server, and I can't tell you how many times I've tried to log in as "r66t".

Comment: Rosie, you raise a valid point. The reason I wrote that is because of the expectation that pressing `o` yields an "o". When NumLock is on, that yields a "6" (hidden under `*`, ha!). If one uses a numpad to type `1966`, it yields `19→→` if NumLock is *off*. So, users from both camps can be caught off-guard, regardless of the default value. So it is not that the system sneakily *changed* the state; nowadays people use diverse keyboards in different places, a system can't guess what this user is used to. Numlock=off is the lowest common denominator, as more and more keyboards don't have numpads.

Comment: Fn-Keys are usually not mapped using NumLock. I guess one of the reasons is this issue. On quite a few devices using Fn-Keys, I never saw one using NumLock for switching. Usually you need to always press Fn, sometimes there is an option to reverse the behaviour (e.g. on notebooks, where multimedia keys are the default an Fx keys need Fn you can often switch this in the BIOS).

Comment: I agree with Rosie, changing a user’s default behavior is not good UX and most of all will lead to fewer errors. I also agree with the answer, if this is a necessary consideration to display the state on screen.  I’d argue it isn’t necessary as billions of people have been fine for decades.

Comment: You sure numlock is used to activate the numpad overlay? The color of those keys suggests it’s a <kbd>Fn<kid> type of situation

Comment: eckes, as far as I remember - you're right, *physically*, one toggles the key state using an <kbd>Fn+something</kbd> combo. However, on a software layer it shouldn't matter - if Numlock was turned off using an API, the pressing the keys will yield letters, rather than numbers.

Answer (score 9):

It's a bad UX practice primarily because the user **is not** expecting this to happen. Users will attempt to do an action and will not be able to do so.

Answer (score 4):

> Many login screens automatically deactivate the Num Lock key on the keyboard before the user can enter their password.

I don't believe that this is true.

It may be that Num Lock happens to be off when at a login screen, but I doubt that the login screen is actively turning it off.  That is, it's not intentionally done as some way to enhance security (because it doesn't); it's an artifact of how the rest of the system is designed.

On Windows, whether Num Lock is on or off is a *user*-specific preference.  If you have a multi-user system and one person prefers Num Lock on and another user prefers Num Lock off, what should the behavior be at the login screen when no one is logged in?

If I log out, my preferences should no longer be active.  Instead, the "default" user's preferences become active, and those are likely to have Num Lock off because that's the safer default for compact/laptop keyboards. (On Windows, this would be stored in the registry, encoded in `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators`.)

Comment: As far as I understand, this regedit attribute is only read after startup, and doesn't have any influence on the login screen. NumLock status also seems to be independent from BIOS settings, at least on my Win10.